# can we create stand alone application for Spring boot web mvc using Electron tool?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, web, electron

I am trying to create a stand-alone application for spring boot. I have a code of `spring boot` mvc and I am trying to build a desktop application using `Electron` tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, able to make desktop version of spring boot project using electron.
For this have to run the command

> mvn clean install -Pproduction

it will prepare two setups(32/64 bit) in the target folder.

Comment: for all that want to to this, but don't have the correct project yet: i THINK OP is referencing this repository: https://github.com/appreciated/maven-springboot-electron

Answer (score 2):

Electron is an executable client application (.exe or .tar.gz or .dmg) that downloads, installs and runs natively on the end user's PC/Mac.

Electron apps themselves are usually written in a JavaScript language (e.g. TypeScript). I'm not aware of a Java based version of Electron - but if you're comfortable with a small amount of JavaScript, you may be able to code most of your application in Spring.

The "server side" of your application (e.g. the API and even front end code such as MVC controllers etc) can be developed in any language you choose.

You can think of Electron apps as a customized Chrome web browser that points only at your application (if you so choose). You can control which pages display and which back end API's are called. A normal icon is created and the app feels "native".

If your application needs to support "offline" scenarios, where the back end of the application runs on the client machine, it should in theory be possible to ship a client side Spring (Java) run-time container to the customer as part of the Electron download. I've never tried this but depending on your scenario it might be desirable.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.. Recently I built the desktop app with spring boot backend. I have also wrote how to do it here : “Modern desktop application with electron.js and Spring boot” by Amit Bhave https://link.medium.com/1IJbo9pcs3